# Convert CFG to CNF Arithmatic Expression

Tags: context-free, computation-models, chomsky-hierarchy

Convert CFG to CNF

The Grammar

```
E→E+T
E→T
T→T*F
T→F
F→(E)
F→x
```

Step 1
Assign variables to terminals

```
A→ +
B→ *
C→(
D→ )
F→x
```

Step 2

```
Remove epsilon which in this grammar is not available
```

Step 3

```
Remove useless symbols which there are none
```

Step 4
Remove unit rule

```
S→E
E→T
T→F
So we have
E→T*F|E+T
T→(E)|x
F→(E)|x
```

Step 5
Add a start symbol

```
    S→T*F|E+T
E→T*F|E+T
T→(E)|x
F→(E)|x
A→ +
B→ *
C→(
D→ )
F→x
```

Step 6
Convert in the form A→BC and A→a
Until now we have

```
S→T*F|E+T
E→T*F|E+T
T→(E)|x
F→(E)|x
A→ +
B→ *
C→(
D→ )
F→x
```

Using terminal variables we get

```
S=EAT|TBF
T→CED|x
E→EAT|TBF
F→CED|x
A→ +
B→ *
C→(
D→ )
Let 
A_1=AT
B_1=BF
E_1=ED
```

So final CNF is

```
S=EA_1 |TB_1
T→CE_1 |x
E→EA_1 |TB_1
F→CE_1  | x
A→ +
B→ *
C→(
D→ )
F→x
A_1=AT
B_1=BF
E_1=ED
```

But after converting I cannot deduce this string from gammar

```
(((x+(x)∗x)∗x)∗x)
```

THanks
Rahman

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in step 4. You need to do it progressively, in particular $E\rightarrow T$ is not just replaced with $E\rightarrow T\ast F$, but by all possible things that $T$ can be replaced by. In this case, that includes the rule $T \rightarrow F$. So the unit rule gets propagated to $E \rightarrow F$, which then has to be replaced in turn giving $E \rightarrow T \ast F \mid (E) \mid x$.

Check this for all rules, and you're a step closer to the correct answer.

Comment: should not it also be E→T∗F∣(E)∣x | E+T

Comment: My reduced form is the following S=E+T |T * F |(E) |x|ε
T→T * F |(E) |x
E→E+T |T * F |(E) |x
F→(E) |x

Comment: @MohammadRahman Yes, sorry, left the obvious bit out :D